# Inject dynamic templates to List component in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, components, ionic3

**I have done so far**

I am new to ionic &  built a List component in ionic 3 which fetches JSON data from server..and passes to list template as a result it shows the list layout on pages wherever I am specifying list selector.

**Requirement**

I need to display different list layouts **[List Dividers,
List Headers,Icon List,Avatar List etc...]** in my app in same/different pages..how can I make component which after fetching data from server passes to dynamic template to make  required list layout.is there a way to pass dynamic templates in components ?

Comment: I think you have to check sidemenu sample application of ionic 3

Answer (score 0):

Angular allows templates to be dynamic themselves. Therefore, "Passing" a template is the same thing as just creating a new component for each of those requirements and using each one of them based on some condition.

If I understand correctly. You are fetching some server side data, and based on what that data contains, you may need to use additional components in your list **[List Dividers, List Headers,Icon List,Avatar List etc...]**?

If that is true, you have a couple options.

1. Figure out all your different conditions for different list types. If you have 2 or more different list types, just create components for each list type that is toggled by *ngIf's.
2. Create one large list component that has all the conditionals in the template. This would be a cluttered approach.

Component interactions are handled by inputs and outputs, or services. Ionic also throws an events api at you that you could use. In general, this is a good reference: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score -1):

I know, this question is old, but for the other visitors, the official tutorial by Angular is the better way to start, i think.

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

I hope it help someone.